# why toast need the context?

Tags: android, toast

I have problem in understanding context class.
why does `Toast.makeText` need context class?

```
public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html

Answer (score 3):

Feel free to examine the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/Toast.java) to learn where the `Context` is used in `Toast`.

For example,

- System resources
- Your app's resources in case a string resource id is used.
- Application package information
- System services such as `LayoutInflater` and `AccessibilityService`

Answer (score 0):

A context is the current state of the application/object. The toast function must have a context to know where it has to show the toast. Check out this post for more info on the context! [What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android)